# setState with setInterval in it gets triggered 3 times

Tags: reactjs

I have a chart that I made with chartJS that I update in a way that makes an animation, and I do that with setInterval, I wanted to be able to pause/resume the animation.

So I created a state variable that tracks the interval ID so that I can kill it when the pause button is clicked:

```
const intervalIDs = [];

function App() {
  const [times, setTimes] = useState(2); // variable that I need to change to make my animation work
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
  const [animationIntervalID, setAnimationIntervalID] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
      setAllData(calculateNewData()); // recalculate data for the chart when times changes
  }, [times])


  const startVisualizationHandler = () => {
    console.log("called"); // gets called once as it should
    setAnimationIntervalID(prevInterval => {
      console.log("setting interval"); // this gets called just ONCE
    
      let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
          setTimes(prevTimes => prevTimes + 0.1);
      }, 100);

      intervalIDs.push(intervalID); // this pushes THREE interval ID's into the intervals array

      return intervalID;
    });
  }

  const pauseVisualizationHandler = () => {
    clearInterval(animationIntervalID);
    setAnimationIntervalID(prevID => undefined);
  }

  const resumeVisualizationHandler = () => {
    startVisualizationHandler();
  }

  const handlePause = () => {
    setPaused(pauseStatus => {
      !pauseStatus ? pauseVisualizationHandler() : resumeVisualizationhandler();
 
      return !pauseStatus;
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ maxHeight: 600, maxWidth: 600, height: 600, width: 600, display: "inline-block" }}>
        <Line data={allData} options={options} width={null} height={null} />
        <button id={"vishandler"} onClick={startVisualizationHandler}>
          VISUALIZE
        </button>
        <button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={handlePause}>
          {paused ? `RESUME` : `PAUSE`}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I run the code, with multiple console.logs spread out throughout the code, I have tracked everything, and when I click the pause/resume button, everything gets called just once in order, just like it should. However, the `setAnimationIntervalID` within `startVisualizationHandler` is acting extremely wierd, the `console.log("setting interval");` gets called just once, but `intervalIDs.push(intervalID);` gets called 3 times, because when I log intervalIDs I see 3 IDs.

What I am trying to do is:

-> onClick on the `VISUALIZE` button -> start the animation - this is working, BUT it also ends up firing multiple `setIntervals` (which to me basically means that the pause/resume functionality is irrelevant to the issue)

-> onClick on the `PAUSE` button -> pause the animation - this is also working

-> onClick on the `RESUME` button -> resume the animation - this is also working BUT it ends up firing multiple `setIntervals`.

Comment: @rayhatfield I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Where exactly in the code are you talking about? Also I have figured out that even just starting the visualization triggers the interval 2 times (adds 2 IDs) so the resume/pause functionality is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: it might related to `React.StrictMode` tag wrapping your App application. try removing, to verify if it persists

Comment: @buzatto yes that fixed it, thank you! You can add it as an answer so that I can accept it, and I'll go to read something about that :)

Comment: Glad it worked out! You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is related to `React.StrictMode` wrapping your App Application. [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) doesn't affect production, only development to find potencial problems. it does that by rerending your component, which results in these unexpected behavior.

to fix it, remove the wrapping `StrictMode` tag from your App.